# Query to group by values in one column, plus identify if a specific value in a 2nd column appears at least once in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is related to the results I received in this question:

[Query which displays a table along with indications of which rows match another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660283/query-which-displays-a-table-along-with-indications-of-which-rows-match-another)

With some query results or a table I'm trying to identify, for each Box id, if all instances of that Box id has a 'yes' in another column, or if there is at least one 'no'. All yes's would result in yes, any no's would result in no.

eg

If this was a table:

```
ID, Box, Match
1,Box100, yes
2,Box100, yes
3,Box100, yes
4,Box200, yes
5,Box200, no
6,Box200, yes
7,Box300, yes
8,Box300, yes
9,Box300, yes
10,Box400, no
11,Box400, no
12,Box400, yes
```

What would be the query to provide these results

```
Box100, yes
Box200, no
Box300, yes
Box400, no
```

I tried to union two queries, one for the yes one for the no, using the UNIQUE statement to return only one, but that of course returns:

```
Box100, yes
Box200, yes
Box200, no
Box300, yes
Box400, yes
Box400, no
```

Which isn't what I am looking for.

I also found this to be very difficult to determine what to call this, and therefore search for solutions, hence my perhaps convoluted title. So apologies in advance.

I feel like the solution is probably pretty easy but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `no` and `yes` are strings, you can simply use aggregation:

```
select box, min(match) as match
from t
group by box;
```

This works because of the alphabetical ordering of the values.  A more general solution is:

```
select box,
       (case when sum(case when match = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'no' else 'yes'
        end) as match
from t
group by box;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that seems to do the trick, plus I added a 'order by box' at the end so I get a nice ascending order list of box ids plus their completeness status. Thanks again. And thanks for the explanation of the 'trick' this particular scenario allows, plus the alternate solution for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is what I would most likely use, however you could do it this way ....

```
declare @example as table (
    exampleID int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   box       varchar(255) not null
,   match     varchar(25) not null
);

insert into @example (box, match) 

select 'Box100', 'yes' union all
select 'Box100', 'yes' union all
select 'Box100', 'yes' union all
select 'Box200', 'yes' union all
select 'Box200', 'no' union all
select 'Box200', 'yes' union all
select 'Box300', 'yes' union all
select 'Box300', 'yes' union all
select 'Box300', 'yes' union all
select 'Box400', 'no' union all
select 'Box400', 'no' union all
select 'Box400', 'yes';

    select distinct a.box
         , isnull(b.match, c.match) match
      from @example a
 left join @example b
        on a.box = b.box
       and b.match = 'no'
 left join @example c
        on a.box = c.box
       and c.match = 'yes'
```

> Result Set:

```
box     match
Box100  yes
Box200  no
Box300  yes
Box400  no
```